# Netbeans 7.4 , Git, opening cloned project

Tags: git, netbeans, clone

I cloned a project from github through netbeans 7.4 and want to work on it through netbeans only. but i cant open the cloned project in netbeans, what do I have to do inorder to work on that project through netbeans?

Comment: Is it Java? Does it uses Ant? Maven? Which project?

Comment: Its a simple JAVA Swing Chess project

Comment: All I want is to get myself familiarize with the features of Git, Have started reading the GIT tutorial now

Comment: Does it use ant, maven or what for the build?

Comment: Still a novice in these stuff, I dont have much idea about what these things are and how are they usefull.